# View end result of Makefile "expansion"

Tags: makefile

I am trying to understand what the end product of this Makefile which uses eval. Is there a way to view the effective end product of what the Makefile looks like as if eval weren't used?

```
VALID_TOOLCHAINS := newlib glibc pnacl

NACL_SDK_ROOT ?= $(abspath $(CURDIR)/../../..)
include $(NACL_SDK_ROOT)/tools/common.mk

TARGET = nacl_io
DEPS = nacl_io
LIBS = $(DEPS) ppapi pthread

CFLAGS = -Wall
SOURCES = handlers.c \
  nacl_io_demo.c \
  queue.c

$(foreach dep,$(DEPS),$(eval $(call DEPEND_RULE,$(dep))))
$(foreach src,$(SOURCES),$(eval $(call COMPILE_RULE,$(src),$(CFLAGS))))

ifeq ($(CONFIG),Release)
$(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(TARGET)_unstripped,$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
$(eval $(call STRIP_RULE,$(TARGET),$(TARGET)_unstripped))
else
$(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(TARGET),$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
endif

$(eval $(call NMF_RULE,$(TARGET),))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know of two ways:

1. replace `eval` with `info`
2. run `make -p` and find your rules explicitly written in the output of that